# pg_dump fails, no space left, need to delete partial backup file to free space

Tags: postgresql, database-backup, dump

Easy points. On my mac, postgres.app 9.2, I ran "pg_dump pdbt > pdbt.sql". It used up all my space and then failed with the error below. Now I want to free up the space taken up by "pdbt.sql" but I cannot find this file. How do I get the space back?

Error message: pg_dump: [archiver] could not write to output file: No space left on device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hrm. The file should be there in its truncated form. If not, you may wanna run a disk verify in Disk\ Utility.app to look for bad file pointers & whatnot.

Comment: I cannot find the file using a search. What path might it be at?

Comment: Ok I repaired my hard drive through disk utility and I deleted a zero byte file called "pdbt.sql" in the /Users/robbie/Library/Application Support/Postgres/var directory. HOWEVER, this only freed up 4 gb of space, while I expected it to free up 170gb. How do I free up the remaining space?

Comment: Ok I found the file. Basically it was a second "pdbt.sql" file and was located directly in /Users/robbie. I deleted it and the space returned. Thanks.